# Stepping back in DatePeriod loop

Tags: php

As I understand I can't set the foreach loop back by variable steps, so I use a for loop like this:

```
$beginDate = new DateTime( $firstday );
$endDate = new DateTime( $lastday );
$endDate = $endDate->modify( '+1 day' ); 
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($beginDate, $interval, $endDate);

$datesArray=array();
foreach($period as $dt) $datesArray[]=$dt->format('Y-m-d');

for ($dateindex=0; $dateindex < count($datesArray); $dateindex++) { 
    ...
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, use

```
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('-1 day');
```

then work out the difference in days between `$endDate` and `$beginDate`, and use that difference in your loop:

```
$beginDate = new DateTime('2016-11-28');
$endDate = new DateTime('2016-12-07');
$endDate = $endDate->modify( '+1 day' ); 
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('-1 day');
$diff = $endDate->diff($beginDate);
$period = new DatePeriod($beginDate, $interval, $diff->days);

$datesArray=array();
foreach($period as $dt) $datesArray[]=$dt->format('Y-m-d');

var_dump($datesArray);
```